# How to set a return intent for an activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two separate activities that both can reference a third activity. Basically I wanted the third activity to understand which of the two has called it, and then return to that activity when the time is appropriate. I have seen and understand the "putExtra", but passing it off as a string, and then using string functions (such as .equals()), seems to be an inefficient way to understand what to return to. Is there a better way of doing this that I'm not familiar with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your activity started as Activity for results then you can use [getCallingActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCallingActivity%28%29), otherwise it seems only option is pass something as part of Bundle to identify which activity called the other activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use integer values to put in `extras` of intent to compare to.

In anycase you will have atleast a single comparison of values to determine the activity which started it...